# How to disable adaptive hibernate

Tags: windows, windows-10, sleep, hibernate

After a Windows Update a few days ago, I noticed my Surface Book started automatically hibernating after entering standby for only 30 minutes, even on a full battery. Under advanced power options, the Hibernate after sleep on battery is set to 1200 minutes (20 hours) which Windows respected prior to the recent Windows update.

The event log showed the reason as "User Away Predicted". Upon some Googling, the behavior seems to be part of a feature called [Adaptive Hibernate](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/hardware/mt732711(v=vs.85).aspx). Trying a command from that page `powercfg /setdcvalueindex scheme_current sub_presence standbybudgetpercent 50` gave an `Invalid Parameters` error.

*Windows seem to think it's smarter than me about my usage -- how do I wrestle control back and disable this annoying "feature"?*

---

The two relevant event log entries:

```
Log Name:      System
Source:        Microsoft-Windows-Kernel-Power
Date:          3/31/2017 9:55:29 PM
Event ID:      42
Task Category: (64)
Level:         Information
Keywords:      (70368744177664),(1024),(4)
User:          N/A
Computer:      SURFACE-BOOK
Description:
The system is entering sleep.

Sleep Reason: Hibernate from Sleep - User Away Predicted
Event Xml:
<Event xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/win/2004/08/events/event">
  <System>
    <Provider Name="Microsoft-Windows-Kernel-Power" Guid="{331C3B3A-2005-44C2-AC5E-77220C37D6B4}" />
    <EventID>42</EventID>
    <Version>3</Version>
    <Level>4</Level>
    <Task>64</Task>
    <Opcode>0</Opcode>
    <Keywords>0x8000400000000404</Keywords>
    <TimeCreated SystemTime="2017-04-01T01:55:29.009291800Z" />
    <EventRecordID>6671</EventRecordID>
    <Correlation />
    <Execution ProcessID="4" ThreadID="9836" />
    <Channel>System</Channel>
    <Computer>SURFACE-BOOK</Computer>
    <Security />
  </System>
  <EventData>
    <Data Name="TargetState">5</Data>
    <Data Name="EffectiveState">5</Data>
    <Data Name="Reason">11</Data>
    <Data Name="Flags">0</Data>
    <Data Name="TransitionsToOn">16</Data>
  </EventData>
</Event>

Log Name:      System
Source:        Microsoft-Windows-Kernel-Power
Date:          3/31/2017 9:25:38 PM
Event ID:      172
Task Category: (203)
Level:         Information
Keywords:      (1024),(4)
User:          SYSTEM
Computer:      SURFACE-BOOK
Description:
Connectivity state in standby: Disconnected, Reason: Policy Setting
Event Xml:
<Event xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/win/2004/08/events/event">
  <System>
    <Provider Name="Microsoft-Windows-Kernel-Power" Guid="{331C3B3A-2005-44C2-AC5E-77220C37D6B4}" />
    <EventID>172</EventID>
    <Version>0</Version>
    <Level>4</Level>
    <Task>203</Task>
    <Opcode>0</Opcode>
    <Keywords>0x8000000000000404</Keywords>
    <TimeCreated SystemTime="2017-04-01T01:25:38.720738500Z" />
    <EventRecordID>6666</EventRecordID>
    <Correlation />
    <Execution ProcessID="4" ThreadID="8020" />
    <Channel>System</Channel>
    <Computer>SURFACE-BOOK</Computer>
    <Security UserID="S-1-5-18" />
  </System>
  <EventData>
    <Data Name="State">2</Data>
    <Data Name="Reason">1</Data>
  </EventData>
</Event>
```

Comment: Try `powercfg /setdcvalueindex scheme_current sub_presence standbybudgetpercent 0.5`. Or try reading the currently set value.

Comment: Hmm your command didn't give an error so maybe it worked. How do you read the current value? `/query` didn't show any value under `SUB_PRESENCE`

Comment: I tried /q too, but it didn't work (VM). But did it solve your problem?

Comment: Unfortunately it didn't. Running `/SYSTEMSLEEPDIAGNOSTICS`, I found that there's a **Smart User Presence Prediction Information** section under each session which implies that it's trying to learn my behavior, though it seems to be pretty bad at it. Not sure how to make sense of the data though, do you have any idea?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Go to (New) Settings->Power and Sleep.

In there, switch off "Save me power when my device knows I'm away."